# how check privilege for user permission has implode?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I add values to user_privilege column by implode consist of permission of user that is 
 ( 7gz,agt_courses,newbill,new_Trainee)=> each of them in real to open (say :newbill page) or not upon user permission 
in user_privilege column in "login" table in database 
in other words  I want to check the user login  his permission if it has say newbill permission he can open newbill page if not he can't open this page .

login table in database like this:

```
**username       username2          user_privilege**

amal             amal         7gz,agt_courses,newbill

ahmed           ahmed         dataDisplay,previllige,newUsers



$username = $_POST['username'];
$username2 = $_POST['username2'];

if($username && $username2)
{
    $finduser = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM LOGIN 
    WHERE username='".$username."' AND username2='".$username2."' AND FIND_IN_SET('Customers', user_previllige)") or die("error");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($finduser) !=0)
        {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finduser))
                {$uname = $row['username'];
                $uname2 = $row['username2'];
                            $arr=explode(",",$row['user_previllige']);}
        }

        if($username == $uname && $username2 == $uname2 && user_previllige =='customer)

            {$_SESSION['sessionname'] =$uname;
            $_SESSION['sessionname2'] =$uname2;
            header ("location:../customers/cutomer.php");}
                else echo '<script>function
{alert(you have not permission to open this page)}</script>';

    }
```

Comment: A properly normalized database would be a better approach to the problem

Comment: As you're using MySQLi, why aren't you using prepared statements?

Comment: and possibly an exit after your header line would help

Comment: how can I do normal DB for preivileges

Comment: Move the user_privilege column into its own table with one row for each user/privilege combination

Comment: but the admin who add privileges to users and every user has many privileges

Comment: Yes, so! That just means it's a table with a few rows in it: as long as it's properly indexed, what's the problem with that? It's using comma_separated lists, as you're doing now, that causes real problems